# contents of SingleChildScrollView isn't becoming full height

Tags: flutter

I have a `SingleChildScrollView > Column > [A bunch of widgets, Text (really long text)]`
I'm trying to make the Text go to the bottom of the screen so I tried 2 things and they both gave me errors

I tried adding a `Spacer` before the Text, but I got a `RenderFlex` error. I then tried wrapping all the widgets in a second column and leaving the Text widget in the 1st/original column. I also got an error with that.

How can I make the Text Widget go all the way to the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

In `SingleChildScrollView` you can't use `Spacer` or `Expanded` widget. You should give height to your widget. I offer you try `Stack` widget like code below:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text('test'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```